# (Navigation component) How to display back arrow on the activity when back to the home fragment?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have to fragments discount fragment and edit service fragment displayed on Edit Service activity.
the back arrow displayed on discount fragment when i back to edit service fragment the arrow disappear i want to display it to navigate the previous activity from edit service activity.

activity layout 
.........................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar_hesham"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="@string/edit_service"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_edit_service"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_hesham"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/edit_service_nav" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/confirm_request_bottom_sheet"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity code 
.............................................................

```
public class EditServicesActivity extends BaseActivity<MainViewModel> {


    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void initActivityComponent() {
        component = ProServeTechApp.getComponent(this)
                .plus(new ActivityModule(this));
        component.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_edit_services;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<MainViewModel> getViewModelClass() {
        return MainViewModel.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initActivity() {
        viewModel.getRequestDetails(getIntent().getExtras().getString("requestId"), String.valueOf(0));
        viewModel.getIssues(getIntent().getStringExtra("requestId"));

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_hesham);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_edit_service);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController );

    }



}
```

navigation 
........................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/edit_service_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/edi_service_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/edi_service_fragment"
        android:name="com.unicomg.proservetech.ui.requestdetails.edit.service.fragments.EditServiceFragment"
        android:label="@string/edit_service"
        tools:layout="@layout/edit_service_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_edi_service_fragment_to_discount_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/discount_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_up"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_bottom"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_up"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_bottom" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/discount_fragment"
        android:name="com.unicomg.proservetech.ui.requestdetails.edit.service.fragments.DiscountFragment"
        android:label="@string/add_discount"
        tools:layout="@layout/discount_fragment">


    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [`setupWithNavController(Toolbar, NavController)` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)):

> The start destination of your navigation graph is considered the only top level destination. On all other destinations, the Toolbar will show the Up button.

If you want to also show the Up button on your start destination (i.e., to go to the previous activity), you'd want to use the version that takes an `AppBarConfiguration`.

As per the [Update UI components documentation on AppBarConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration), `AppBarConfiguration` allows you to set exactly what destinations you want as top level destinations. To get the Up button to show on every destination, you'd use an empty set of top level destinations:

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
    new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build();
```

Note that since you're using `setSUpportActionBar()`, you should follow the [Action Bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar) and use the `setupActionBarWithNavController()` method rather than the `Toolbar` version. You must also override `onSupportNavigateUp()` to handle the up button.

Therefore your complete code would look like:

```
public class EditServicesActivity extends BaseActivity<MainViewModel> {


    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public AppBarConfiguation appBarConfiguation;
    public NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void initActivityComponent() {
        component = ProServeTechApp.getComponent(this)
                .plus(new ActivityModule(this));
        component.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_edit_services;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<MainViewModel> getViewModelClass() {
        return MainViewModel.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initActivity() {
        viewModel.getRequestDetails(getIntent().getExtras().getString("requestId"), String.valueOf(0));
        viewModel.getIssues(getIntent().getStringExtra("requestId"));

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_hesham);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_edit_service);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,
            appBarConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, it is a perfect solution!

Comment: Thank you. The part that got me was that first part from the documentation. I didn't know the start destination is considered top level and therefore doesn't have the navigation button.

Comment: if you are wondering how to catch the back press when you are on the home destination check if backstack is poped or not, if it's not poped then you are at the home destination as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63059587/6039240
`fun onSupportNavigateUp:Boolean{ if(navCont.navigateUp()==false) finish()}`